# jQuery onfocus and onblur event minification

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see I am trying to increase the height of the text field when the user types into it and when he clicks away (element loses focus) I am making it smaller.

Is there a simpler way to write the following code?

Simple HTML input field:

`<input type="text" />`

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input').on('focus', function() {
        $(this).height('20px');
    });

    $('input').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).height('12px');
    });

});
```

Comment: You could do this with just CSS: `input:focus { height: 20px; }`

Comment: Well I am learning jQuery and would like to know the jQuery way no CSS way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done more-efficiently with just CSS, but using jQuery, you could use event delegation.

```
$(document).on('focus blur', 'input', function(e) {
    $(this).height(e.type === 'focusin' ? '20px' : '12px');
})
```

For completeness, here's the CSS solution:

```
input {
    height: 12px;
}
input:focus {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @Robert I had the event mixed up, it might work now. I'm on mobile right now, so I can't test it.